# How to prevent the keyboard from showing (not dismissing) on a TextView?

Tags: ios, keyboard, textview

I would like to know how to **DISABLE** (not how to dismiss) the iOS keyboard in a TextView. I don`t even want the keyboard to show up when the user touches the TextView.

All of the examples I found were to make the keyboard disappear AFTER it appears.

The closest thing I got was to set textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; but that gets rid of the scrolling as well (**I want to keep the scrolling**).

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Also two good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170278/how-to-disable-keyboard-on-a-uitextview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to implement the following method in text view's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: That did it! I can`t believe it was that simple =) Thanks a lot man!