# How to disable keyboard on a UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

I have used a Text view in my app for iPad on xib. I wrote some text on it. Now while the app is running and the user is reading that text, if he accidentally touches the screen a keyboard appear. I want to disable that keyboard popping out. How should I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also achieve this via Interface Builder by unchecking the Behavior Editable box in the Attributes Inspector tab.

[image: Interface Builder Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 16):

Try setting the editable mode off:

```
textView.editable = NO;
```