# Keyboard in iPad (ios6.01)making my web page mess up with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, cordova

I am creating hybrid application with help of phone gap which supports in iPad.The iPad version is 6.1 . My issue is Whenever i tried to enter values in fields using default iPad keyboard, my web page is moving little bit upwards then if i click any button in application page with out manually closing the keyboard my page is messing up.

What i tried is when ever i click my page button while keyboard is opening i just fired window.scrollTo(0,0).But in some scenarios this fix is not helping.So please any one help out to resolve this issue.How can i hide the keyboard by code or its great if any one give other ideas using HTML5..If Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable iOS keyboard (don't show it at all) in phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923313/disable-ios-keyboard-dont-show-it-at-all-in-phonegap)