# changing keyboard in cordova phonegap in iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is it possible to change the display of the keyboard in a cordova phonegap application running on iOS? I want to experiment with leaving off certain keys and changing its size.

I take it if this feature is locked down then maybe an alternative would be disabling the keyboard ([i could do so this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923313/disable-ios-keyboard-dont-show-it-at-all-in-phonegap)) and then writing one from scratch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this is blocked in IOS7 and earlier. your not allowed to do so its a security feature. thus is impossible as of right now.