# How to disable the virtual keyboard in GWT based application?

Tags: gwt, virtual-keyboard

Were are developing a kiosk application in GWT and for that, we are using custom virtual keyboard and we want to disable the default virtual keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent the keyboard from showing (not dismissing) on a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957363/how-to-prevent-the-keyboard-from-showing-not-dismissing-on-a-textview)

Comment: But i want it in GWT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Got the solution by using JSNI(native javascript) and it works perfectly, but i don't know it is the best way. I have written code such as follows. 
step1:
Get an id of the active element(i.e., INPUT and type="text"  element) 
step2:
Then immediately call the blur() event on that element (Now the element will lost it's focus and default virtual keyboard doesn't showup)
step3:
Now again immediately call the focus() event on the same element(Note: Keyboard doesn't show up here, it just unblur that element ).
step4:
Now by using the retrieved id, enter the data into textbox through custom virtual keyboard.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try set the property `inputView`?

If you set, the default virtual keyboard won't show up.

Comment: Thank u for your response. Actually we developing this app in GWT and we cannot use that inputVIew property to hide the keyboard.

Comment: @user3548310 I'm not familiar with GWT, is there anyway to control the native system in GWT? Or you can just show your virtual keyboard and respond user touch and update the related UI.

Comment: Got the solution by using JSNI(native javascript), but i don't know it's the best way. Thank for your suggestion @ Puttin